# I have no "export as" option avaliable

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i want to set embed color profile but i have no "export as" option. what can i do?

I tried to find sulotion in google but
unsuccessfully.

[image: export problem]

Answer (score 2):

"Export As" was a feature added to **Creative Cloud versions** of Photoshop. It was **not** a feature available in legacy versions.

From your screenshot, it appears as though you *may* be using **Photoshop Creative Suite 6** ...which has no "Export As" feature. There's nothing you can do to "add" it other than upgrading the application and subscribing to the Creative Cloud.

I can't recall specifically, but "Export As" *may* have also not been available in the first couple released of the Creative Cloud.

For legacy versions of Photoshop, using **Save For Web** was more apprpriate for jpg/png/gif saving. It allows you to embed a color profile, metadata, etc.. or strip them away.

Comment: Before Export as… There was [& still is] Save for Web. I still actually use that in a quick action, as it doesn't throw away all your exif data like Export does.